# Using HTML5 local storage to store list items <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am creating a basic to-do list and was wondering on how to store my list so that when a user comes back to the page or accidentally refreshes the browser window, the list will still be available?

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>My To-Do List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-animation.min.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <header>
                <img src="images/checklist.png" alt="some_text">
            </header>
             <h2>MY TO-DO LIST</h2>

            <ul id="sortable"></ul>
            <form id="newItemForm">
                <input type="text" id="itemDescription" placeholder="Add Description" maxlength="40" />
                <input type="submit" id="add" value="add" />
                <div id="double">Drag and drop to rearrange items
                    <br />Click on an item to remove it</div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/sort.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
$(function () {

    var $list;
    var $newItemForm;
    var $newItemButton;
    var item = '';
    $list = $('ul');
    $newItemForm = $('#newItemForm');
    $newItemButton = $('#newItemButton');

    // ADDING A NEW LIST ITEM
    $newItemForm.on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var text = $('input:text').val();
        $list.append('<li>' + text + '</li>');
        $('input:text').val('');
    });

    $list.on('click', 'li', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var complete = $this.hasClass('complete');

        if (complete === true) {
            $this.animate({}, 500, 'swing', function () {
                $this.remove();
            });
        } else {
            item = $this.text();
            $this.remove();
        }
    });

});

localStorage.setItem($list);

//add animations when you learn how to...
```

Comment: For `setItem` you need to provide some `key`. It takes 2 parameters `key` and `value`

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the data in an object also. Currently its only in DOM. Everything you add a new todo or edit an existing todo, you need to save that to the localstorage. Storing DOM nodes to localStorage wont work. localStorage also only accept string values.

So this is how I would change your code:

```
// localStorage key
var lsKey = 'TODO_LIST';

// keeping data
var todoList = {};

function getSavedData () {
    var fromLs = localstorage.getItem( lsKey );

    if ( !! fromLs ) {
        todoList = JSON.parse( fromLs );
    } else {
        todoList = {};
        localstorage.setItem( lsKey, todoList );
    };
};

function saveData () {
    var stringify = JSON.stringify( todoList );
    localstorage.setItem( lsKey, todoList );
};

$newItemForm.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var text = $('input:text').val().trim(),
        uuid = new Date.now();

    // lets use input[type:checkbox] to determine if complete or not
    if ( !! text ) {
        todoList[uuid] = text;
        $list.append('<li><input type="checkbox" id=' + uuid + ' /> ' + text + '</li>');
        $( 'input:text' ).val( '' );
    };
};

$list.on('change', 'li input', function() {
    var uuid = $(this).attr( 'id' ),
        $li  = $(this).parent();

    if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
        todoList[uuid] = undefined;
        delete todoList[uuid];

        saveData();

        $li.fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $this.remove();
        };
    };
});
```

Good luck, have fun!

Comment: Damn gotta modify a lot of things haha

Comment: All this code can get small if you use any MVC BackboneJs or AngularJs. Here is a plunker with backbone todo: http://plnkr.co/edit/iBnqVN?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You have to do 2 things: first is to store ony your data, not html. Second thing is that you have to provide a name for your item in `localStorage` because this is a key/value storage,  so it needs a name for a key. Also because `localStorage` stores all data as a string value, call `JSON.stringify()` on your data before you sore it. So your code will be something like this: `localStorage.setItem("yourKeyName", JSON.stringify(yourDataObj))`. And when you want to read your data from it do `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("yourKeyName"))` to get your data as json object